# Setting Goal Position with Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to make the mobile robot move autonomously.

Now I want to give a coordinate of goal position to my robot, but I don't know how?

My desired interface is simple like this.

- click some point in gzclient window
- then mobile robot starts moving to there.

For this, I think I need to pick the coordinate of the mouse pointer when mouse was clicked.

Is there any way to solve this?

I found this [solution](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5091/get-mouse-click-location-and-event/?answer=7583#post-id-7583) but it only extracts position on the client window(not the coordinate of gazebo world).

---

solution

I could get mouse position in the gazebo world by using `gui::MouseEventHandle` and `Scene::GetFirstContact` method. Thank you for answering.

```
#include <gazebo/math/Rand.hh>
#include <gazebo/gui/GuiIface.hh>
#include <gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>
#include <gazebo/gui/MouseEventHandler.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/MouseEvent.hh>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

namespace gazebo
{
    class SystemGUI : public SystemPlugin
    {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// \brief Destructor
    public: virtual ~SystemGUI()
        {
            this->connections.clear();
            if (this->userCam)
                this->userCam->EnableSaveFrame(false);
            this->userCam.reset();
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// \brief Called after the plugin has been constructed.
    public: void Load(int /*_argc*/, char ** /*_argv*/)
        {
            this->connections.push_back(
                    event::Events::ConnectPreRender(
                            boost::bind(&SystemGUI::Update, this)));

            gui::MouseEventHandler::Instance()->AddPressFilter("glwidget", boost::bind(&SystemGUI::OnMousePress, this, _1));
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        // \brief Called once after Load
    private: void Init()
        {
        }

        boost::mutex mutexMouseClicked;
        math::Vector2i mouseClicked;
        bool isMouseClicked;
    private: bool OnMousePress(const common::MouseEvent& _event)
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutexMouseClicked);
            mouseClicked = _event.pos;
            isMouseClicked = true;
            std::cout<<"Clicked at "<<mouseClicked<<" of screen "<<std::endl;
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// \brief Called every PreRender event. See the Load function.
    private: void Update()
        {
            if (!this->userCam)
            {
                // Get a pointer to the active user camera
                this->userCam = gui::get_active_camera();
            }
            // Get scene pointer
            rendering::ScenePtr scene = rendering::get_scene();

            // Wait until the scene is initialized.
            if (!scene || !scene->GetInitialized())
                return;

            if(isMouseClicked && this->userCam){
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutexMouseClicked);
                math::Vector3 position_clicked;
                scene->GetFirstContact(this->userCam, mouseClicked, position_clicked);
                std::cout<<"Clicked at "<<position_clicked<<" of world\n"<<std::endl;
                isMouseClicked = false;
            }
        }

        /// Pointer the user camera.
    private: rendering::UserCameraPtr userCam;

        /// All the event connections.
    private: std::vector<event::ConnectionPtr> connections;
    };

    // Register this plugin with the simulator
    GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(SystemGUI)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9050/setting-goal-position-with-gazebo/) by [bazzisniper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1280/bazzisniper/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-07-03**:
I tried nearly the same thing some days ago but for me it seems to steal the Gazebo mouseClick events which makes the 3D viewport unusable is this effect the same for you??

**Comment by [bazzisniper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1280/bazzisniper/) on 2015-07-03**:
If you mean that you couldn't navigate in 3D view by **3D viewport unusable** , that was not the case with me. I could navigate the gazebo world as usual.

**Comment by [vishnurs](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3151/vishnurs/) on 2017-03-31**:
When I try to compile the code, I am getting the following error. /usr/local/include/OGRE/Paging/OgrePagingPrerequisites.h:32:31: fatal error: OgrePrerequisites.h: No such file or directory #include "OgrePrerequisites.h" I have no clue if I have to install anything. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try using [GetFirstContact](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/82b3f2539fe8027b36dc6b32b12ed586da2dd8c1/gazebo/rendering/Scene.hh?at=default#cl-309) from a [gui system plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=system_plugin&cat=write_plugin).

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bazzisniper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1280/bazzisniper/) on 2015-07-03**:
Great. Thank you so much. I solved problem. :D